# How to use $lte to filter out string value from json

Tags: json, mongodb, express, mongoose

[image]

**I have to filter on the basis of contentRating**

Return videos with “contentRating” set to 12+ or lower (%2B is “+”  encoded - Ref) - All videos a user of age 12 can watch will be returned i.e, videos of content rating - “Anyone”, “7+”, “12+”

How can I use $lte on string. It's not working, any other alternate way to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Is the contentRating field enumeration/a fixed set of values? If thats the case, using `$in` to find specific values could be a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of field `contentRating` is `string`, use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator as,

```
db.collection.find({"contentRating":{ $in:["Anyone","7+","12+"]}})
```